# Move blocks to other container how to

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks, containers

Being newby I look for a workaround to move **Sign in** and **Store switcher** from `header.panel` to `header.container`. I just tried this code but won't work

```
<referenceContainer name="header.container">
        <referenceBlock  class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store.settings.language" template="switch/languages.phtml"> </referenceBlock>
</referenceContainer>
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

There is a new **move** node in the layout XML that we have access to in M2.  This node sets the declared block or container element as a child of another element in the specified order.

**Example:**

```
<move element="name_of_an_element" destination="name_of_destination_element" as="new_alias" after="name_of_element_after" before="name_of_element_before"/>
```

In the example you provided before you should just be able to call:

```
<move element="store_settings_language" destination="header_container" as="store_settings_language"/>
```

More information in the official M2 docs on `<move>` here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html#fedg_layout_xml-instruc_ex_mv

Answer (score 9):

This is better:

```
<move element="store_language" destination="header.container" />
```