# How to move attributes in magento 2.2.x?

Tags: product-attribute, custom-attributes, magento2.2.6

I want to move some attributes, but I don’t see any settings for this.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to community. You can do this from your layout file. Check this link: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/109703/move-blocks-to-other-container-how-to

Comment: Thanks. I moved short description, but I don't see the custom attribute in my layout file :( How can I find it?

Answer (score 0):

I would achieve it this way:

In your theme: `Theme > Magento_Catalog > layout > catalog_product_view.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="alert.urls">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="your-attribute" before="product.price.tier" template="catalog/product/view/custom-template.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Now, in your `Theme > Magento_Catalog > tempaltes > catalog/product/view/custom-template.phtml`

```
<?php $product = $block->getProduct();?>

<div class="">
   <?php echo $product->getData('my_attribute');?>
</div>
```

Then, for bottom attributes, I would hide/remove them from css or from backend config.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I try it, but nothing happened.
My custom attribute is "material".

Comment: https://i.ibb.co/mBvZNz2/z-Kh-RRb-Gi-D-A.jpg


https://i.ibb.co/cw464sY/GFi5-L1e-SKj-U.jpg

Comment: You must have `<referenceContainer name="alert.urls">` in your layout.