# How to display the product reviews without tab in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product, review, tabs

I want to display the products review below the product without Tab.

like this revies in the red box:
[image]

[image]
Please suggest something for the same

Comment: please explain briefly or attach any screen shot for more idea

Comment: I think you want to show the reviews in the main content of the product view page. If yes, this might help you https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/109703/move-blocks-to-other-container-how-to

Comment: No, It didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

```
<?php
$productId = '323'; // Product ID
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->create("Magento\Catalog\Model\Product")->load($productId);
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$currentStoreId = $storeManager->getStore()->getId();
$rating = $objectManager->get("Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\CollectionFactory");

$collection = $rating->create()->addStoreFilter(
            $currentStoreId
        )->addStatusFilter(
            \Magento\Review\Model\Review::STATUS_APPROVED
        )->addEntityFilter(
            'product',
            $productId
        )->setDateOrder();

print_r($collection->getData());
            ?>
```

You will get review data in **$collection->getData()**. you can display as per your requirement.

Please let me know still if you face issue.

Comment: Thanks! But need something more.